# React component rerender multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I have faced with react component multiple re-rendering problem while writing socket io chat application. The backend side is on Nodejs and sends everything properly, while on receiving new messages at the client-side my component re-renders in (x+7) times every time I receive a new message from a socket and try to update my messages list. I also tried to leave **useEffect** dependency parameter as an empty array, however, in this case, I every time get empty array instead, while it should be already an array with existing messages. I posted the code below, and a screenshot from the console of the browser. Will be very glad, if someone can explain how to fix this issue.

[image]

```
import React,{useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import MessageItem from './MessageItem';
import {Context} from '../../store/Store';
import socket from '../../utils/socket';
import {actions} from '../../reducers/actions';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import SpringScrollbars from '../../utils/ScrollBar';

let test = 0;

function MessageFrame() {

    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        socketOnListeners();
        test++;
    }, [messages]);

    const socketOnListeners = () => {

      socket.on("joinCompleted", data => {
        const allMessages = [...messages];
        allMessages.push(data);
        setMessages(allMessages);
      });

      socket.on("room-changed", data => {
        console.log('we changed the roomm', data);
        let allMessages = [];
        allMessages.push(data.message);
        setMessages(allMessages);
        dispatch({type: actions.NEW_ROOM, payload: data.room});
      });

      socket.on('newMsgSaved', data => {
        let allMessages = [...messages];
        console.log('we are initializing', allMessages);
        if(allMessages.length > 1000) allMessages = [];
        allMessages.push(data);
        setMessages(allMessages);
      });

  
      socket.on('user-left-room', data => {
        const allMessages = [...messages];
        allMessages.push(data);
        setMessages(allMessages);
      });

      socket.on('userExit', data => {
        const allMessages = [...messages];
        allMessages.push(data);
      });

      // return () => socket.disconnect();

    }


    return (
        <SpringScrollbars 
            autoHide={true}
            renderView={props => <div style={{padding: '0 25px 0 15px', ...props.style}} />}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '90vh' }}>
              {test}
            <List>
                {messages.length > 0 ? messages.map((el,idx) => {
                    let direction = 'right';
                    if(el.type === 'system'){
                      direction = 'center';
                    }
                    else if(el.type === 'current'){
                      direction = 'left';
                    }
                    return (
                        <MessageItem key={idx} data={el} direction={direction} />
                    );
                }) : null}
            </List>
        </SpringScrollbars>
    )
}

export default MessageFrame;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
First need to remove `message` dependency on the useEffect because it creates a lot of callbacks for one event.
Second is to use `setMessage` with callback to get the current, updated `message`, seems like when you try to access state of message in socket.on callback it doesn't provide you with the current one but shows the one that was during the initialisation. But when you access message throught `setMessage` callback then you get the most recent updated `message` and this way you can stack them together.
here is the solution:

```js
socket.on('newMsgSaved', data => {
     setMessages(currMessages => {
          let allMessages = [...currMessages];
          if (allMessages.length > 1000) allMessages = [];
          return [...allMessages, data]
     });
});
```

Comment: If I remove message as a depency, I only see last added message, previous messages are gone.

Comment: `newMsgSaved` is resposible for adding new messages?

Comment: yes, it is added a new message to "messages" array by trigging setMessages(), and then these "messages" are looping via .map() method and show its values.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by I only see last added message, it renders only last message or you receive you one meesage? can you provide more information, it is kind of hard to help with only this code. For use initialization should be done once and there should not be message in dependancies

Comment: При каждом получении нового сообщения, я обновляю массив с уже заранее созданными сообщениями (метод newMsgSaved). Однако, каждый раз, копируя массив и выводя его в консоль я вижу пустой массив в который добавляется только что пришедшее сообщение. Хотя там должны быть заранее добавленные элементы. Суть ясна?)

Comment: yes, how big is the `allMessages.length` right now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217107/discussion-between-elman-huseynov-and-evgeny-klimenchenko).

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of useEffect's second argument is to do a shallow equal check on what's passed in. You can work around this by either making sure you pass the same instance of the array, or by passing values that can be compared shallowly in the array.
A good reference article here https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14324